# (Mysql) how to create a column is to multiply two columns

Tags: mysql

```
| id  |  price  |   quantity  |  total  |
|  1  |   5     |      5      |    25   |
```

I want to create a total = price * quantity column. What I have to do??

Comment: Note that it's not recommended to store derived data

Answer (score 0):

You could use generated column:

```
ALTER TABLE tab
ADD COLUMN total INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (price*quantity) STORED;
                 -- INT or any appropriate data type
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fc8a3892be1b8c978c935e77fb9009be)**